# how do i use a bluetooth mac keyboard on ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

i tried to use a wireless apple keyboard with my custom built ubuntu Pc and the key board layout is shifted. i tried using a different layout several times but it still refuses to work properly. any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The layout changes when you have Num Lock, so you get some sort of numpad in the middle-right of the keyboard. Just plug another keyboard to disable Num Lock and try again.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me on Ubuntu 16.10. It's completely ridiculous.

Comment: This is the exact solution that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the Ubuntu Bluetooth stack can behave erratically and prevent you from connecting your Apple Bluetooth Keyboard (or other bluetooth device).  So to connect an Apple Bluetooth Keyboard to Ubuntu [This may help](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-963641.html)

Also, you might want to look [At this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard) for the description the default behavior of every Apple keyboard.

Comment: i just left num lock on my previous keyboard, but thanks anyway, your fix did work.

Comment: The 2nd link helped; owner of a Keychron K2 mechanical BT keyboard, double-tapping the fn+F6 key combination managed to dislodge the numpad.

Answer (score 1):

For those working with a laptop and the older (cylindrical top) Mac Bluetooth keyboard (which has no number pad), make sure that on the laptop keyboard the numlock is *disabled*.

My configuration is Ubuntu 18.04 and Lenovo Ideapad 520

(This would be a comment except not enough rep points to do that)